# Github raw xml: accents not working on raw link

Tags: xml, github, iso-8859-1

I've uploaded a xml to github.
It works fine on this link:
https://github.com/fundamentosdeenfermagem/fundamentosdeenfermagem.github.io/blob/master/banco/banco.xml

But when I get the raw link to work with it on code that's what I get:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fundamentosdeenfermagem/fundamentosdeenfermagem.github.io/master/banco/banco.xml

I get

Pensamento Cr�tico e Racioc�nio Cl�nico

Instead of

Pensamento Crítico e Raciocínio Clínico

Even though I've set the encoding to ISO-8859-1. I don't know what to do about github, or where else to host the files.

Thank you.

Comment: Use utf8 content type and add a <![CDATA[     ...  special characters  ... ]]> if the xml isn't valid due of special characters.

Comment: just made a test using í and it didn't work https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fundamentosdeenfermagem/fundamentosdeenfermagem.github.io/master/banco/banco.xml

Comment: Ok first you didn't use correctly <![CDATA but in you case the problem come before the xml was generated, i think it come from a database by a script server that manipulate this datas. 2 solutions : look at the database to check if database is set as utf8 general ci or in the server script as PHP, JSP, ASP... you have to use some function of this language to formated correctly your datas before parsing to a XML file.

Comment: @headmax CDATA is completely irrelevant for character encoding issues. All it means is that `&` and `<` don't need to be escaped, and that's not the issue here.

Comment: It worked when I manually went on github, created a file and pasted the content. The problem seems to exist only when using Github for desktop, which bothers a lot cause now I cannot commit any other change without bugging my xml.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fundamentosdeenfermagem/fundamentosdeenfermagem.github.io/master/banco/banco2.xml